# Download word docx from API with AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to download a Word docx document from my PHP Api with AngularJS, however whenever I try to do so I end up with a corrupted file that Word cannot read.

Here is my angular code :

```
  $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'gen/gen_dup.php',
        data: data,
        transformRequest: $httpParamSerializer,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('Duplicata MB OK', response);
        var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' });
        saveAs(file, 'filename.docx');
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('error', response);
    });
};
```

My PHP page's code (I'm using TinyButStrong to generate the documents) :

```
<?php
  include_once('tbs_class.php');
  include_once('tbs_plugin_opentbs.php');
  $TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
  $TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);

$type = $_POST["type"];

if ($type == "1") {
     $TBS->LoadTemplate('templates/duplicata.docx');
} else {
     $TBS->LoadTemplate('templates/scompte.docx');
}

  $title = $_POST["title"];
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $address = $_POST["address"];
  $reference = $_POST["reference"];
  $tmp = $_POST["collector"];
  $collector = $collectors[$tmp];
  $mcollector = $mcollectors[$tmp];

  $TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD);

  ?>
```

That is what I receive back from the PHP :

[image]

Which is my docx file, but when I try to download it is corrupted. Am I doing something wrong ? By the way, when I am sending data through a regular HTML form to the PHP page (and consequently go to this page), the download starts automatically and the file is perfect. Any suggestion ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that could help anyone else, I figured it out, the problem was some code in my PHP file was generating some warnings, and those warnings were somehow corrupting the file I was downloading. Getting rid of anything else than the Word document data solved this issue.